# Convergence in Hilbert spaces.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces

> Let $\mathbb{X}$ be a Hilbert space and $ \{e_ {n}: n \in \mathbb {N} \}$ an orthonomal subset. Does the series $ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} |\langle x, e_n\rangle |$ converge for every $x \in \mathbb{X}$?

I was thinking, can we take $x = \sum_{n \in \mathbb {N}} e_{n}$? Does that make sense? For in this case $\langle x, e_n \rangle = 1$, for every $n$ and therefore our series does not converge.

Comment: I am afraid your suggested $x \not \in \mathbb{X}$. Consider for example $\mathbb{X} = \ell^2$ and $e_i$ to be the standard basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=\ell^2$ and $\{e_ {n}: n \in \mathbb {N} \}$ the usual orthonormal basis of $X$.

Let $x=(\frac{1}{n})_{n \in \mathbb N}$, then $x \in X$ and $<x, e_ {n}> =|<x, e_ {n}>|=\frac{1}{n}.$

Hence the series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} |<x, e_ {n}> | $ is divergent.

Comment: +1 But the sum of the squares of those coefficients will converge, to the square of the norm of $x$.